# handling .html as .php (lighttpd)?

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, lighttpd

I am trying to rewrite all .php pages to be .html. I'm using this expression:

`url.rewrite-once                   = ( "^(.*)\.php$"    => "$1.html" )`

And it works, until I use `$_GET` arguments.

How can I make it so `http://website.com/search.php?find=query` will just be `http://website.com/search.html?find=query` ?

Preserving the arguments when it is passed through `mod_rewrite`?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9700916/html-through-php-parser/9701044#9701044

Comment: Not using apache, lightty http://www.lighttpd.net/

Comment: Thought it may be useful to you.

Comment: I'm sorry vascowhite. It was helpful thank you.

Comment: In my answer I may have misunderstood your question.  Are all of your files .html and you want them to be parsed as PHP?  Or do you just want to rewrite fake `.html` urls to actual `.php` files?  Are you using FastCGI?

Comment: @drew010 I am using fastcgi yes.  Currently all my files are .php. I'm just trying to fake the urls as being .html.

Comment: Ok in that case my answer should work okay.  I use FastCGI in lighttpd as well and I use a similar rewrite rule for some URLs and it works fine both with and without query string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
url.rewrite-once = ( "^(.*)\.php\??(.*)?$" => "$1.html?$2" )
```

This should match with or without query string arguments.

Since you are trying to make `.php` files appear as `.html` files, I think the expressions may be reversed.  You will want to match on `.html` and rewrite to the `.php` file.

Answer (score 1):

The following changes to /etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf file allow php to be executed inside .html files.

I commented out this line

```
server.modules = (
     "mod_access",
     "mod_alias",
     #"mod_compress",
     "mod_redirect",
}
```

and included this line

```
fastcgi.map-extensions    = ( ".html" => ".php" )
```

then restarted the server

```
sudo service lighttpd force-reload
```

The reference I used:
http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/lighttpd-map-html-pages-to-php-execute-html-pages-as-php.html