# Replace .php with .html for all urls in files directory

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

How can I Replace .php with .html ?

I have all files with .php extension in my **files** directory

```
/files
  foo.php
  bar.php
```

I want browser to show them as

```
  http://example.com/files/foo.html
  http://example.com/files/bar.html
```

Is this possible by .htaccss?

Comment: Really, you should search or try something before asking a question. There are so many results for this exact question, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4548860/replacing-php-ext-with-html-through-htaccess

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this to your `files/.htaccess`

```
 RewriteEngine on 
 RewriteBase /files/ 
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /files/$1.php [NC,L]
```

this rewriteRule will redirect all `.html` requests to `.php` meaning that if you enter `www.example.com/files/foo.html`then it will be internally redirected to `www.example.com/files/foo.php` and your browser will remain at `www.example.com/files/foo.html`

Answer (score 1):

You need to use URL Rewrite on your .htaccess file, there is a post with the same question and is solved already here :

[Rewrite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2878559/how-do-i-rewrite-php-to-html-using-htaccess-rules)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
RewriteEngine on  
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} (.*)\.php  
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php $1.html [R=301,L]  

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} (.*)\.html  
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html $1.php [L]
```